# Prevent Windows 10 locking if sleeping for a short time

Tags: windows-10, sleep, password-protection

Is there a way to keep Windows 10 requiring password on wakeup from sleep, but only after a certain period of time, e.g. 15 minutes?

Comment: What form of sleep are you talking about? Just a turned of display, actual sleep or even hibernation?

Comment: I mean actual sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a default option for this. If you really want to get this to work you will have to rely on third party tools and/or use a script.

If you go for the script solution you would (most likely) need to disable the locking and use a periodically running script to lock it after a while. Detecting that the user was/is idle that way is probably going to be difficult.

You could try to disable the password on resume from sleep through the power options and set your screensaver on a 15 minute timer and let it require the password if you try to deactivate it.

Comment: I tried the screensaver -- it doesn't work if you bypass the screensaver (going to sleep on request). Scripting would be too messy, so I guess the answer is "no" :-). But thanks!